# Numpy 2D-array sets the value of a cell when it is not needed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write minesweeper in python. A bomb is a cell with a value less than 0. The values of cells that differ from the position of the bomb cell by one column and one row in all directions should increase by 1. But the values of cells that are far from the bomb often increase. Please help me

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint


#Settings
rows = 10
columns = 10
bombs = 10


def createfield(rows=rows, columns=columns, bombs=bombs):
    minefield = np.full((rows, columns), 0)
    def createbomb():
        bombcount = 0
        random_cell = ((randint(0,rows-1), randint(0,columns-1)))
        minefield[random_cell] = -9
        for item in minefield.flat:
            if item < 0:
                bombcount +=1
        if bombcount < bombs:
            createbomb()
    createbomb()
    return minefield

def setnumbers(array=createfield()):
    for item in (tuple(zip(*(np.nonzero(array < 0))))):
        row, column = item
        print(row, column)
        try:
            array[row-1, column-1] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            array[row-1, column] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            array[row-1, column+1] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            array[row, column-1] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            array[row, column+1] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            array[row+1, column-1] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            array[row+1, column] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            array[row+1, column+1] += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass

    return array
field = setnumbers()
print(field)
```

[image]

Replacing np.full with np.zeros, changes in the replacement algorithm do not help

New setnumbers function:

```
def setnumbers(array=createfield()):
    for row in range(rows-1):
        for column in range(columns-1):
            if array[row,column] < 0:
                print(row, column)
                for rs in range(-1, 2):
                    for cs in range(-1, 2):
                        try:
                             array[row-rs, column-cs] += 1
                        except IndexError:
                            pass
    return array
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRsS5.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJIfS.png)

Comment: As a debugging suggestion, did you try reducing the size of the grid / number of bombs? What is the minimal configuration that produces unexpected results?

Comment: Note: You should avoid using mutable objects (e.g., `np.array`) as default arguments. This is probably not your problem, but it could lead to other problems in the future.

Comment: I would also use `np.zeros` instead of `np.full` and also generalise the loop over all neighbours to limit the possibility you've made a mistake, e.g.
`for rs in range(-1,2):
        for cs in range(-1.2):    
            try:
                array[row-rs, column-cs] += 1
            except IndexError:
                pass`
No idea if your set numbers is the right logic for what you want (and I suspect exceptions are not the best way to do this)

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem 3 rows, 2 columns and 1 bomb configuration have this bug

Comment: You might want to update the question with these parameters, the output you see, as well as the expected result.

Comment: I would suspect the problem is in `item in (tuple(zip(*(np.nonzero(array < 0)))))` which you then try to get the row and colum from. You'd be much better to double nested loop in rows and coumns (`for row in rows:` etc) and then set elements after a logical test like `if array[row,column] > 0:`

Comment: @qazwsxedc, I think your logic is wrong, you need an if statement to check for a bomb only (`if array[row, column] == -9:`) then add numbers. I think you can have a case where two bombs are next to each other, you'd need to make sure you also check and avoid incrementing the -9 cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:
since indexing negative positions in numpy arrays returns actual elements of the structure (e.g. a[-1] returns the last element), you are adding more than what is necessary because the except IndexError: doesn't catch any error (-1 is a valid index).

```
def setnumbers(array=createfield()):
for item in (tuple(zip(*(np.nonzero(array < 0))))):
    row, column = item
    print(row, column)
    if row-1 >= 0 and column-1 >= 0:
        array[row-1, column-1] += 1
    if row-1 >= 0:
        array[row-1, column] += 1
    try:
        if row-1 >= 0:
            array[row-1, column+1] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    if column - 1 >= 0:
        array[row, column-1] += 1
    try:
        array[row, column+1] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        if column-1 >= 0:
            array[row+1, column-1] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        array[row+1, column] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        array[row+1, column+1] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass

return array
```

I removed the unnecessary `except`.
There are much more pythonic and efficent ways of checking index overflow (e.g. compare it with `array.shape`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a numpy array, a standard 2D array would work for you and is better for you to be manipulating.

```
from random import randint
import math

def createbomb():
    bombcount = 0
    random_cell = ((randint(0,rows-1), randint(0,columns-1)))
    minefield[random_cell] = -9
    for item in minefield.flat:
        if item < 0:
            bombcount +=1
    if bombcount < bombs:
        createbomb()

def createfield(rows=5, columns=5, bombs=1):
    minefield =  [ [0]*columns for i in range(rows)]
    
    #initialise bomb positions
    bomb_cells = []
    for bomb in range(bombs):
        #generate random cell position
        rand_cell = randint(0,(rows*columns) - 1)
        bomb_cells.append(rand_cell)
    
    b_row = math.floor(bomb_cells[0]/rows)
    b_column = bomb_cells[0] - (b_row * rows)
    
    print(bomb_cells, b_row, b_column)
    #populate minefield
    for row in range(rows): #go through each row
        for column in range(columns): #go through each column
            
            #check the selected cell against all bombs
            for bomb in bomb_cells: 
                b_row = math.floor(bomb/rows)
                b_column = bomb - (b_row * rows)
                
                if b_row == row + 1 and (column + 1 == b_column or column - 1 == b_column):
                    minefield[row][column] += 1
                elif b_row == row - 1 and (column + 1 == b_column or column - 1 == b_column):
                    minefield[row][column] += 1
                elif b_row == row and (column + 1 == b_column or column - 1 == b_column):
                    minefield[row][column] += 1
                elif b_column == column and (row + 1 == b_row or row - 1 == b_row):
                    minefield[row][column] += 1
                minefield[b_row][b_column] = -1
                    
    return minefield

print(createfield())
```